Hyphenation is switched off when text should fade away
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\babelprovide[hyphenrules=ngerman-x-latest]{ngerman}
\usepackage{gradient-text}

\batchmode

\begin{document}

\section*{Der Schattenmann}
\begin{sloppypar}\tolerance 20
\parshape=36
0pt 0.4\textwidth
0pt 0.4\textwidth
0pt 0.4\textwidth
0pt 0.4\textwidth
0pt 0.4\textwidth
0pt 0.4\textwidth
0.55\textwidth 0.45\textwidth
0.55\textwidth 0.45\textwidth
0.55\textwidth 0.45\textwidth
0.55\textwidth 0.45\textwidth
0.55\textwidth 0.45\textwidth
0.55\textwidth 0.45\textwidth
0pt 0.4\textwidth
0pt 0.4\textwidth
0pt 0.4\textwidth
0pt 0.4\textwidth
0pt 0.4\textwidth
0pt 0.4\textwidth
0.55\textwidth 0.45\textwidth
0.55\textwidth 0.45\textwidth
0.55\textwidth 0.45\textwidth
0.55\textwidth 0.45\textwidth
0.55\textwidth 0.45\textwidth
0.55\textwidth 0.45\textwidth
0pt 0.4\textwidth
0pt 0.4\textwidth
0pt 0.4\textwidth
0pt 0.4\textwidth
0pt 0.4\textwidth
0pt 0.4\textwidth
0.55\textwidth 0.45\textwidth
0.55\textwidth 0.45\textwidth
0.55\textwidth 0.45\textwidth
0.55\textwidth 0.45\textwidth
0.55\textwidth 0.45\textwidth
0.55\textwidth 0.45\textwidth
\noindent\gradientRGB{„Er ist verrückt“, dachte sich der kleine Jan, der im Treppenhaus des Mehrfamilienhauses saß, in dem er mit seinen Eltern wohnte und den Kater der Nachbarin streichelte. „Herr Veith ist alt und verrückt“. Seine Tür stand immer einen Spalt weit offen, egal ob bei Tag oder Nacht, und man hörte ihn wirres Zeug flüstern. Wenn es so leise war wie jetzt, glaubte man, die Worte entschlüsseln zu können, die er brabbelte. Doch so sehr man sich auch darauf konzentrierte, es war unmöglich, den Sinn dieses Kauderwelschs zu entziffern. Jan fuhr Felix, dem Kater, über den Rücken. Mit der anderen Hand stützte er seinen Kopf und starrte durch das große Fenster hinunter in den dunklen Hof vor dem Haus, der gerade von einem heftigen Sommerregen überschwemmt wurde. Felix hasste den Regen, für Jan dagegen war es im Moment ein willkommener Zeitvertreib, den Tropfen beim Fallen zuzusehen. Der Regen besaß die Eigenschaft, die Menschen in ihre Häuser zu treiben und was noch besser war, er sorgte für Ruhe, indem er die meisten Geräusche dämpfte. Abgesehen von der Stimme von Herrn Veith, der offensichtlich mit sich selbst redete, da er ohne Punkt und Komma in einem Schwall fortfuhr und nie eine Antwort abwartete.}{0,0,0}{255,255,255}\end{sloppypar}
\end{document}

I would like to fade away this given text. For that purpose I used the gradient-text package. But if I use this package the hyphenation is switched off while the fade away effect works as intended. What I am doing wrong? Is there another package or workaround to achieve this fade away effect while maintaining the hyphenation? Thanks in advance for any help!

unrelated but my comment in golatex says that you should remove the \usepackage[T1,EU1]{fontenc}.  EU1 is obsolete since many years.

@Ulrike Fischer Yes you are right this is my mistake

Off-topic: Because of (the not needed) \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} I assume that you are using PDFLaTeX? Have you recognized, that gradient-text does not work correctly with umlauts or sharp-s in this case? Problems like these are also noted in the manual using \textit as an example. IMHO, the token by token processing also prevents the hyphenation. With native UTF8 engines at least the umlauts and sharp-s would work. So I would recommend to use, e.g., LuaLaTeX.

@cabohah: no, I am using LuaLaTeX. I have no problems with umlauts and sharp-s

So you should really not use \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}. With old versions of inputenc this would not work correctly and with up-to-date versions of LaTeX using it makes no sense, but a warning message, if used with LuaLaTeX: Package inputenc Warning: inputenc package ignored with utf8 based engines.

@cabohah: thank you for your hint! I deleted the line in the preamble but the initial problem still persists.

well it won't work. The package inserts color whatsits before each char and that prevents hyphenation. With lualatex you could use colors based on attributes instead:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{luacolor}
\usepackage{gradient-text}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\gr@dientRGB}[7]{
  \int_set:Nn\l_gtext_MaxIndex_int{\int_eval:n{\str_count:n{#1}}}
  \int_step_inline:nnn{1}{\l_gtext_MaxIndex_int}{
      \exp_args:Ne\str_if_eq:nnTF{\str_item:Nn{#1}{##1}}{~}{}{
        \int_set:Nn\l_gtext_Ratio_int{\int_eval:n{\l_gtext_Ratio_int+1}}
      }
      \color@RGB\current@color
       {
          \int_eval:n{(\int_use:N\l_gtext_Ratio_int*#5+(\l_gtext_MaxIndex_int-##1)*#2)/\l_gtext_MaxIndex_int},
          \int_eval:n{(\int_use:N\l_gtext_Ratio_int*#6+(\l_gtext_MaxIndex_int-##1)*#3)/\l_gtext_MaxIndex_int},
          \int_eval:n{(\int_use:N\l_gtext_Ratio_int*#7+(\l_gtext_MaxIndex_int-##1)*#4)/\l_gtext_MaxIndex_int}
       }
      \set@color
      \str_item:Nn{#1}{##1}
  }
}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff
\textwidth=4cm
\begin{document}
\gradientRGB{„Er ist verrückt“, dachte sich der kleine Jan, der im Treppenhaus des Mehrfamilienhauses saß, in dem er mit seinen Eltern wohnte}{0,0,0}{255,255,255}

\end{document}


